# Is it possible to publish newly created items in Workflow?

Tags: web8, workflow

I want to create a Workflow with the following scenario. A Workflow Process has been configured in Structure Group's property.

1. Editor creates a Page. Then Workflow starts and the created Page gets into the Workflow
2. Editor publishes the Page to Staging site
3. Editor finishes activity and the next activity is assigned to Approver
4. Approver checks the Page's content on Staging site, and approves it.

In this scenario, the problem occurs on 2. A newly created Page has never been checked-in, so it can't be published ("Publish" button on CME is disabled).

I want to make it possible to publish the Page to Staging site, because it's difficult to check contents without seeing the actual published page.

Is it possible to publish the newly created page in Workflow?

If it's not possible, how can the Approver judge whether the page is good or bad? I guess it's very difficult to judge it without actually seeing the published page.

What is common way to use Workflow associated to Structure Group property?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You should see this page: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-081E9E27-0C77-4F24-9E75-FBFA169410DC

in particular, I think you just want to read through

> Publish items that are in progress

Comment: Newly created page in workflow cannot be published, because "Publish" button on CME is disabled. So "publish the in-workflow version" option cannot be used also.

Comment: Argghhh. That's correct - at that point they are only 'workflow' _items_ and there's no Component version (1.0) of them!!! Sorry for the confusion. I've added a note to Sayatan proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible to publish the newly created page through workflow.

You can achieve this by adding an Automatic action (Instead of Manual publishing) in your workflow which will publish the item to staging. (With Bundle or Without Bundle)

Incase you prefer to do it manually then you can ask your editor to create and publish it manually to staging. Once publishing done, then they can add that page in a bundle and start the bundle workflow.

I personally prefer the first option. For more reference you can check below inks -
http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2012/12/quick-review-for-tridion-2013-workflow.html
https://justsayantan.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/start-with-a-simple-workflow-in-tridion/

Comment: Thanks for answer. Making automatic action is good, but is it "common" solution? I mean making program is a little unreasonable, so it should be possible by out of the box functionality(without programming). Or workflow is expected to be used with programming by nature?

Comment: Yes it is very commonly used and purpose of automatic action is to add the customization in the workflow. But if you want to avoid you can try the 2nd option or you can try the xpm  to create/edit the Page.

Comment: In one solution, we have workflow enforced via the schema meaning it can't be added to a container/page etc. until it's been through workflow once. We created a workflow that would create a v1.0 of the component then re-enter it through the same {new workflow instance} workflow with a approval status that would only allow stage publishing. This works fine.